# CSS styling doesn't take into effect inside project tab panel for Jira plugin

Tags: css, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I'm new to Jira plugin development and I'm trying to develop a project tab panel plugin for JIRA (6.3.9).

For tab panel's styling, I've CSS file at "resources/css/tabpanel.css"

Here are the contents of the CSS file:

```css
div.status{
    float:left; 
    min-width:18%; 
    height:auto;
    text-align:center; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    margin:2px;
    background-color: #e6e6fa
}

div.issues{
 background-color:#add8e6; 
 margin:5px; 
 border: 1px;
 text-align:left
}
```

and velocity file has contents like this:

```html
<div class="module">
    <div class="mod-content">
     <div id="statuses" class="aui">
      #foreach($status in $statuses)    
        <div id="status" class="aui" ><Strong>$status.getNameTranslation()</Strong>
       #foreach($issue in $issues)
      #if($status.getId() == $issue.getStatusObject().getId())     
        <div  id="issues">   
       ...
        </div>
         #end      
       #end    
        </div>        
      #end
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

atlassian-plugin.xml has webresources added like this:

```html
<web-resource key="tabpanel-resources" name="tabpanel Web Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <dependency>jira.webresources:jira-global</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="tabpanel.css" location="/css/tabpanel.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="tabpanel.js" location="/js/tabpanel.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
    <context>atl.general</context>
    <context>tabpanel</context>
    <context>jira.general</context>    
</web-resource>
```

However, CSS styling doesnt take into effect in tabpanel, I've tried adding 
$webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("plugin-key:resourceskey")

and

"requireResource("pluginkey:web-resource-key")"

but it doesnt seem to work. Please help me in understanding what's going wrong. I tried to look in atlassian answers page but no help.

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure you're plugin key is correct.** Near the top of your `atlassian-plugin.xml` you should find a line that looks like: `<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" ...>`.

The `project.groupId` is the groupId in your pom.xml, and the `project.artifactId` is the artifactId in your pom.xml.

So lets say your groupId was `com.atlassian.plugins` and your artifactId was `tabpanel`, then using your web resource key which is `tabpanel-resources` (as shown in this line `<web-resource key="tabpanel-resources" name="tabpanel Web Resources">`), the resulting requireResource statement should be:

```
#requireResource("com.atlassian.plugins.tabpanel:tabpanel-resources")
```

This should be put at the top of your Velocity template and the macro will put the resources into the head element of the resulting HTML.

**Possible other cause**

The `#requireResource` part is a velocimacro which is made accessible by the webResourceManager object being available in the Velocity template. So if it doesn't work, make sure an instance of [JiraWebResourceManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/webresource/JiraWebResourceManager.html) is put into a context map for the velocity template with the key of "webResourceManager".